# r - Combine the distinct output in 1 row

Tags: r, distinct, plyr

The code below allows me to see which e-learning module is accessed per day.

`` activity_per_day_which_modules <- ddply(activity, ~Date, distinct, `Which module(s)` = Module) ``

The output is as follows:

| Date | Module |
| --- | --- |
| 22-10-2021 | Food chemistry |
| 22-10-2021 | Food Physics |

How do I tell R to combine the rows into one?

| Date | Module |
| --- | --- |
| 22-10-2021 | Food chemistry, Food physics |
| 23-10-2021 | Food chemistry |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `paste` for this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(Module = paste(Module, collapse = ", "))
```

Note: If your real data has more columns you might want to resort to `mutate` rather than `summarize`, if you do just make sure to do `%>% distinct()` afterwards